# filtering pandas over a list and sending email

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, slack-api

I am having a pandas data frame like below:-

```
    Tweets
0   RT @cizzorz: THE CHILLER TRAP *TEMPLE RUN* OBS...
1   Disco Domination receives a change in order to...
2   It's time for the Week 3 #FallSkirmish Trials!...
3   Dance your way to victory in the new Disco Dom...
4   Patch v6.02 is available now with a return fro...
5   Downtime for patch v6.02 has begun. Find out a...
6   ⛏️... soon
7   Launch into patch v6.02 Wednesday, October 10!...
8   Righteous Fury.\n\nThe Wukong and Dark Vanguar...
9   RT @wbgames: WB Games is happy to bring @Fortn...
```

I also have a list suppose like below :-

```
my_list = ['Launch', 'Dance', 'Issue']
```

Now I want to filter the rows if there is a matching word from the my_list and get the whole row and send it as an email or to slack.

Like I should get output as row no is because its having Dance word in it.

```
3   Dance your way to victory in the new Disco Dom..
```

I tried below code to filter but every time its giving me an empty values

```
data[data['Tweets'].str.contains('my_list')]
```

Also I only wants to send the email the same row as a body if I am having matching words from list else I dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get it done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

s = '''
"RT @cizzorz: THE CHILLER TRAP *TEMPLE RUN* OBS..."
"Disco Domination receives a change in order to..."
"It's time for the Week 3 #FallSkirmish Trials!..."
"Dance your way to victory in the new Disco Dom..."
"Patch v6.02 is available now with a return fro..."
"Downtime for patch v6.02 has begun. Find out a..."
"⛏️... soon"
"Launch into patch v6.02 Wednesday, October 10!..."
"Righteous Fury.\n\nThe Wukong and Dark Vanguar..."
"RT @wbgames: WB Games is happy to bring @Fortn...       plane     5         [20 , 12, 30]"
      '''

ss = StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_csv(ss, sep=r'\s+', names=['Data'])

my_list = ['Launch', 'Dance', 'Issue']

cond = df.Data.str.contains(my_list[0])

for x in my_list[1:]:
    cond = cond | df.Data.str.contains(x)

df[cond]
```

Comment: how i can setup to send the retrieved tweets as an email.

Comment: For email you will have to set up an SMTP server. I’ll send you some likes later tonight

Comment: The first snipped on this link should get the job done https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email . Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Hey pankaj it worked... Can you help me with one more issue..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819833/creating-a-dynamic-twitter-alert-in-python-using-hashing

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex=True`

**Ex:**

```
data[data['Tweets'].str.contains("|".join(my_list), regex=True)]
```

Comment: Rakesh its working flawless...but how i can setup to send it as email.. I mean if you can help me with that part.

Comment: this is giving me the exact match. i mean if downtime is there then it works but if downtime, or Downtime  is there then it wont and